# What are my odds questions

Tags: discussion

[What are the odds I will hit my flush?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-odds-i-will-hit-my-flush) Are we going to allow these types of questions?  The question was asked during commitment but we were told to wait until beta to decide.

Answer (score 2):

### Not Yet

During private beta, it is important to [avoid easy questions and think like an expert](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta).  These questions are not exemplary, expert-level questions, and as such we should not let them right now.

Once the site is more established it might be worth revisiting this question, but at least during private beta I don't think we should allow them.  People that earn their living playing poker won't be very interested sifting through questions about how to calculate odds.

Comment: I don't know...I think first we would have to come to a decision here on meta.  There are other things we need to decide on as a community for the FAQ, so I'm not sure whether or not it makes sense to add this before the full FAQ is ready.

Comment: A more relevant link would be http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta

Comment: @ChrisMarasti-Georg Thanks, I updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

These localized questions should be closed for one, canonical **"how to calculate odds"** question. You better make the answer an awesome one, because there are almost 2.6 million hands in a 52-card deck (before variations), and we're not going to start answering them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no if the question is directly `gimme the odds`, much like homework questions on SO.  If the question is about how to calculate odds for a non-specific situation, that should be allowed.

Answer (score -2):

I feel it is in-line with the original Stack Overflow goal to have an objective answer for on-topic, objectively answerable questions.  It is exactly the kind of question someone might type into Google, and that's what the sites on this network are here to help with.

Comment: Perhaps at some point, but for now we need to worry about how to get experts here.  Basic questions about odds are not likely to attract pros.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan having re-read the beta question FAQ, I agree.